# Django forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField appearance is different when an instance is passed to the form and when the form is empty

Tags: django, django-forms

i have this ModelMultipleChoiceField,

```
    services = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Services.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'select2'}),
        required=False
    )
```

when the i display an empty form it appears like that:
[without instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnNXZ.png)

but when i pass an instance to the form the field appears like that:
[with instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYEjJ.png)

i want both to have  the look of the first screenshot